# Какими инструментами/технологиями должен владеть Java-разработчик?

Tags: java, java-ee

Здравствуйте) Впереди последний курс университета, а знаний по программированию как таковых нет) 
Самостоятельно начал изучать Java, да и научную работу делаю на ней. 
Но разработчик в работе пользуется не только "чистым" языком, а разными технологиями/фреимворками и т.д.
Какими основными инструментами должен владеть Java-разработчик?)

P.S инструменты для разработки веб-приложений и сервисов (Java EE). 
Знаю лишь что нужен Ant, Spring/Hibernate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Грубо говоря, любая программа состоит из 3-х более-менее независимых частей:

1. Морда - то есть то чего показывается юзеру - по научному иногда называется front-end
2. Собственно сама логика - иногда называется business-logic
3. Данные: то с чем оперирует прога включая исходные данные или результаты работы.

2+3 еще иногда называется в сумме back-end

В частных вырожденных случаях прога может не иметь морды (драйвера) или может не иметь данных, а иногда нет и самой логики :)

Применительно к J2EE - предполагается, что в качестве front-end используется JSP/Servlet, для доступа к данным JDBC.

Теперь ближе к делу - к теме вопроса - касательно фреймворков: по сути это надстройки над JSP/Servlet и JDBC. Если фреймворков над JDBC сравнительно немного и стандартом де-факто уже стал Hibernate, то фреймворков/надстроек над JSP/Servlet охрененное количество. Я бы посоветовал начать с самой простой Struts - он прост, прозрачен и позволяет понять вообще принципы построения любого фреймворка.

Отдельно надо сказать о Spring - это я бы сказал набор фреймворков, покрывающий практически весь спектр J2EE, а не только JSP/Servlet - в частности: JMS, бины, JDBC и проч. Орудие тяжелое - я не стал бы рекомендовать его для начала.

По-поводу остального инструментария: настоятельно бы рекомендовал хорошо выучить [Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) - инструментарий логгинга, де-факто промышленный стандарт. Знание ANT неплохое подспорье, кстати, если уж собрались учить ANT, заодно прихватите [maven](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maven) - не помешает.